# Why the level surface is constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Why level surfaces are of the form (,)= or (,,)=?

Are there any good visual representations why it is that?

And why the velocity vector stays constant as well?

Comment: Why don't you write the whole question? Apparently, you want to know why level surfaces are of the form $\;F(x,y)=m\;$ or $\;F(x,y,z)=m\;$ , with $\;m=$ a constant.

Comment: That's exactly my question!

Comment: Ok...because we want to know how the function behaves when we cut from it slices for some constant value $\;m\;$ . That's all. It is not the level surfaces are constant: they're just **defined that way**

Comment: So it's basically like slicing on a certain level? Let's say if x equals 8?

Comment: Have you ever used a topographic map?  They have "contour lines" that connect points on a hill or mountain with the same altitude.  They are handy when hiking because you can see where there is a steep slope (the contour lines are close together) or where the slope is easy (the contour lines are far apart).  The same thing with the "level curves" on a graph.

Comment: I can’t understand where geometrically this C exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the definition of the level curve or level surface.

For example if $$ f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$ The level curves are the sets defined by $$x^2+y^2=C$$ where $C$ is a constant.

As you notice for positive values of $C$ we get circles and for negative values of $C$ the set is empty while for $C=0$ we get a single point.

These are the curves that you get by cutting the paraboloid $$z=x^2+y^2$$ with the horizontal planes $$z=C$$

Comment: In this case why is the rate of change (or velocity) equals to constant as well?

Comment: It depends on the direction of motion.  If you have $x^2+y^2=C$ the total derivative along that curve is $0$ that is $$2xdx+2ydy =0$

Comment: Is there any visual representations of it with tangent line?

Comment: You may visualize a car travelling on a flat road of the same altitude on a mountain where the $t$ represent time.  As long as you travel on the same altitude $dz/{dt$ the rate of change of altitude with respect the time is $0$

Comment: So basically if I slice the paraboloid and get the circles as a contour plot. And my car is travelling at the flat level e.g. z=5, my rate of change equals zero?

Comment: Yes, the rate of change of height with respect the time is $0$

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and you have some value $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then the set of points

$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) = c\}$$

is the  *level surface* for the value c.

Thus, if you say "the level surface is constant," there must be some value $c$ assumed. But, given such a value $c$ it means that the value of the function $f$ is always $c$ for points on the level surface.

Comment: Could you write an example, please? This is not really convincing to me.